# How to convert datetime from one format to another in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

I have datetime in 2 different formats as shown below:
a = 2021-06-18 17:22:19+00:00
b = datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 1, 6, 24, 58, tzinfo=tzutc())

I want to convert b to the format of a and compare which date time is older.
I searched a lot but couldn't find any solution for this.

Can anyone please let me know how could this be achieved ?

Comment: If you want to compare them, don't you need to convert a to b's type?

Comment: If you want to convert a to b, have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Comment: Otherwise: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime

Comment: try `strftime()`

Comment: Are they always the same format?

Comment: @bdbd ... Does this also take time into consideration ?  In my case i need to consider both date and time for comparing which is older.

Comment: And if possible, can you also give me an example as to how it could be done ? @bdbd

Comment: Yes it takes time into consideration. Have a try first and we can guide you through if you get stuck.

Comment: to clarify: `a` is (presumably) a string, `b` is a datetime object - these are different data types, not formats! `a` might represent date/time in a certain *format*. And you can 1) convert the string to a datetime object using `strptime`, and 2) convert the datetime object to a string (that represents date/time in a certain format) using `strftime`.